# If input contains at least one character

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Sorry guys that i am asking a question that has long been answered. But I could not find the answer I needed.

The question is that i want to check value of input. If input after unfocus has one text or more (do something)

```
 var inputLength = $('input').val();
 if (inputLength.length > 1) {
     $('span.input--madoka').addClass('myclass')
 }
 else  {

 }
```

Comment: That's not a question. What specifically is going wrong, and what specifically do you need help with? Did you mean to put the above code inside a handler?

Comment: can you try to put your code in Jsfiddle and show us the issue.? not really understanding.. i think you are missing the handler.

Comment: Yeah that is right but i need a function which will check length of input after blur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <kbd>[blur()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/blur#fn)</kbd> event to call your function when element loses focus

***Here is example***

```js
$('#filter').blur(function() {

  var inputLength = $(this).val();

  if (inputLength.length > 1) {

    console.log('has something');

    // here you add whatever class you want to add to other element

  } else {

    console.log('has nothing');

    // here some other action
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="filter" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```js
var empty = true;
$('#test').on('change', function(){
   if($(this).val()!=""){
      console.log('not empty');
    } else {
      console.log('empty');
    }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Text : <input type="text" id="test" >
```